# Simple Hashmap in C

Tags: performance, c, hash-map

I've been working on a simple hashmap in C. Here is `hashmap.h`:

```c
#ifndef __HASHMAP_H__
#define __HASHMAP_H__

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef size_t (*HashFunction)(void*);
typedef bool (*CompareFunction)(void*, void*);

struct Pair {
    size_t hash_id;
    void* key;
    void* value;
    struct Pair* next;
};

struct HashMap {
    struct Pair** buckets;
    size_t num_buckets;
    HashFunction hfunc;
    CompareFunction cfunc;
};

struct HashMap* new_hashmap(HashFunction, CompareFunction);
struct HashMap* new_hashmap_c(HashFunction, CompareFunction, size_t);

void free_hashmap(struct HashMap*);

void insert_hashmap(struct HashMap*, void*, void*);

void* get_hashmap(struct HashMap*, void*);
void remove_hashmap(struct HashMap*, void*);

#endif // __HASHMAP_H__
```

And here is `hashmap.c`:

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include "hashmap.h"

#define DEFAULT_BUCKETS 750000

struct HashMap* new_hashmap(HashFunction hfunc, CompareFunction cfunc) {
    return new_hashmap_c(hfunc, cfunc, DEFAULT_BUCKETS);
}

struct HashMap* new_hashmap_c(HashFunction hfunc, CompareFunction cfunc, size_t buckets) {
    struct HashMap* hmap;
    hmap = malloc(sizeof(*hmap));
    assert(hmap);

    hmap->buckets = malloc(buckets * sizeof(*hmap->buckets));
    hmap->num_buckets = buckets;
    hmap->hfunc = hfunc;
    hmap->cfunc = cfunc;

    assert(hmap->buckets);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < buckets; ++i) {
        hmap->buckets[i] = NULL;
    }

    return hmap;
}

void free_hashmap(struct HashMap* hmap) {
    free(hmap->buckets);
    free(hmap);
    hmap = NULL;
}

void insert_hashmap(struct HashMap* hmap, void* key, void* value) {
    size_t hashed_key = hmap->hfunc(key);
    struct Pair* prev = NULL;
    struct Pair* entry = hmap->buckets[hashed_key];

    while (entry != NULL) {
        if (hmap->cfunc(entry->key, key)) {
            prev = entry;
            break;
        }
        entry = entry->next;
    }

    if (entry == NULL) {
        entry = malloc(sizeof(struct Pair));
        entry->hash_id = hashed_key;
        entry->key = key;
        entry->value = value;
        entry->next = NULL;

        if (prev == NULL) {
            hmap->buckets[hashed_key] = entry;
        } else {
            prev->next = entry;
        }
    } else {
        entry->value = value;
    }
}

void* get_hashmap(struct HashMap* hmap, void* key) {
    size_t hashed_key = hmap->hfunc(key);
    struct Pair* entry = hmap->buckets[hashed_key];

    while (entry != NULL) {
        if (hmap->cfunc(entry->key, key)) return entry->value;
        entry = entry->next;
    }

    return NULL;
}

void remove_hashmap(struct HashMap* hmap, void* key) {
    size_t hashed_key = hmap->hfunc(key);
    struct Pair* prev = NULL;
    struct Pair* entry = hmap->buckets[hashed_key];

    while (entry != NULL) {
        if (hmap->cfunc(entry->key, key)) {
            prev = entry;
            break;
        }
        entry = entry->next;
    }

    if (entry == NULL) return;
    if (prev == NULL) {
        hmap->buckets[hashed_key] = entry->next;
    } else {
        prev->next = entry->next;
    }
    free(entry);
    hmap->buckets[hashed_key] = NULL;
}
```

And here is my test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "hashmap.h"

size_t hash(void* key) {
    size_t hash = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++) {
        hash = 31 * hash + *((char*) (key + i));
    }

    return hash;
}

bool compare(void* key1, void* key2) {
    return *((int*) key1) == *((int*)key2);
}

int main() {
    struct HashMap* my_hmap = new_hashmap(hash, compare);
    int k = 10;
    int v = 101;
    int v2 = 102;

    insert_hashmap(my_hmap, &k, &v);
    printf("initial value: %d\n", *((int*)get_hashmap(my_hmap, &k)));

    insert_hashmap(my_hmap, &k, &v2);
    printf("value after changing: %d\n", *((int*)get_hashmap(my_hmap, &k)));

    remove_hashmap(my_hmap, &k);
    printf("pointer to deleted value: %p\n", get_hashmap(my_hmap, &k));

    free_hashmap(my_hmap);
    printf("done!");
}
```

Any tips on performance, coding style, etc. would be nice. Thanks!

Comment: That's an awful lot of default buckets. There are numerous bugs, too. Try your code with a hash function that returns a constant (i.e., every insert results in a hash collision). Then try another where that constant is, say, 1000000 (some number greater than `DEFAULT_BUCKETS`). In your test code, why is a map that stores integers using a string based hash computation?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm -- I seem to have gotten the incorrect hash function. Also, I did expect there to be bugs in the code; It's the first time I have ever written a hashmap and I haven't written C code in a while.

Comment: I would change the number of buckets to: `749993` closest prime to `750000` this will help you avoid collisions.

Answer (score 6):

Urgs, the first impression is already bad:

```c
#ifndef __HASHMAP_H__
```

Every identifier that starts with a double underscore is reserved for the implementation of the C compilation environment (compiler + operating system). Since you are not working on the implementation but are rather an application developer, you must not define these identifiers. Instead, use the commonly accepted pattern of `PROJECT_FILE_H`, with `PROJECT` and `FILE` being placeholders.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
```

It is common to sort the headers alphabetically, at least those from the C standard library. Both `stdlib.h` and `stdbool.h` come from the standard library.

```c
typedef size_t (*HashFunction)(void*);
typedef bool (*CompareFunction)(void*, void*);
```

These typedefs are almost reasonable. Since these functions are not supposed to modify their arguments, you should replace `void *` with `const void *`.

```c
struct Pair {
    size_t hash_id;
    void* key;
    void* value;
    struct Pair* next;
};
```

The name `Pair` is wrong for this struct, it should rather be called `HashMapEntry`. A pair typically has 2 fields, not 4, and these fields are called `first` and `second`.

```c
struct HashMap {
    struct Pair** buckets;
    size_t num_buckets;
    HashFunction hfunc;
    CompareFunction cfunc;
};
```

To quickly see if the map is empty (if you need it), you could add a `size_t size` field.

```c
struct HashMap* new_hashmap(HashFunction, CompareFunction);
struct HashMap* new_hashmap_c(HashFunction, CompareFunction, size_t);
```

All these function declarations look good. To get rid of the `struct` keyword, you should `typedef struct HashMap HashMap;`.

Next, the implementation.

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include "hashmap.h"
```

Looks great. Putting assertions all over the code is good style. That is much better than comments of the kind "I expect that this variable is never NULL".

```c
#define DEFAULT_BUCKETS 750000
```

Whoa, that's a high number. Other HashMap implementations typically use a default bucket count of 16.

```c
struct HashMap* new_hashmap_c(HashFunction hfunc, CompareFunction cfunc, size_t buckets) {
    struct HashMap* hmap;
    hmap = malloc(sizeof(*hmap));
    assert(hmap);
```

This assertion is dangerous since it goes away when you compile the code with the preprocessor flag `-DNDEBUG`. You must either ensure that your code is always compiled with assertions enabled, or `if (hmap == NULL) enomem()`.

```c
    hmap->buckets = malloc(buckets * sizeof(*hmap->buckets));
```

This multiplication might overflow if the number of buckets is really high. This will probably not happen though. If your HashMap has to cope with untrusted input, you risk a buffer overflow and a security vulnerable, allowing every attacker to run arbitrary code on your computer.

The rest of `new_hashmap_c` looks fine, except for the `assert`.

```c
void free_hashmap(struct HashMap* hmap) {
    free(hmap->buckets);
    free(hmap);
    hmap = NULL;
}
```

There is no point in setting `hmap = NULL` at the end. This will only influence the local variable `hmap` inside the function `free_hashmap`. If the calling function has a variable, that variable will not be influenced at all and still point to the freed memory. That's ok because the caller is not supposed to do anything with that variable anymore.

```c
void insert_hashmap(struct HashMap* hmap, void* key, void* value) {
    size_t hashed_key = hmap->hfunc(key);
    struct Pair* prev = NULL;
    struct Pair* entry = hmap->buckets[hashed_key];
```

That's bad design. Your `HashFunction` is supposed to return a number in the range `[0, hmap->num_buckets)`, but the field `num_buckets` should not be accessed by any code outside your own implementation. Therefore the `insert_hashmap` should ensure for itself that the return value of the hash function is in the correct range, using this simple one-line change:

```c
    struct Pair* entry = hmap->buckets[hashed_key % hmap->num_buckets];
```

The rest of `insert_hashmap` looks fine, except for the missing null check after `malloc`, as explained above.

The function `get_hashmap` looks perfect.

The function `remove_hashmap` looks perfect.

Next and last: the test code.

```c
size_t hash(void* key) {
    ...
        hash = 31 * hash + *((char*) (key + i));
```

I wonder how you got the compiler to accept this broken code. `key` is a void pointer, and one cannot do arithmetic using void pointers. The usual way to deal with this is to convert the void pointer into a string pointer first:

```c
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++) {
```

Calling `strlen` in a loop is expensive. This is because in C, the function `strlen` is very inefficient. It needs to look at every character of a string until it finds the `'\0'` that terminates the string. If you have a string with 1_000_000 characters, this will take 500_000_000_000 memory accesses, which is really slow. The usual pattern in C is to start with a pointer to the beginning of the string and to advance this pointer until it points to the `'\0'`, like this:

```c
size_t hash(const void* key) {
    size_t hash = 0;
    for (const unsigned char *p = key; *p != '\0'; p++) {
        hash = 31 * hash + *p;
    }
    return hash;
}
```

```c
bool compare(void* key1, void* key2) {
    return *((int*) key1) == *((int*)key2);
}
```

Ah, so the HashMap maps string keys to int values. These facts should be represented in the function names. Instead of `hash` and `compare`, these should rather be called `hash_str` and `compare_int`.

```c
int main() {
```

The empty parentheses `()` mean that this function takes an arbitrary number of arguments. This was a historical accident. In modern C (since 1990), you have to write `(void)` here to state that the function takes no arguments at all.

```c
    struct HashMap* my_hmap = new_hashmap(hash, compare);
    int k = 10;
    int v = 101;
    int v2 = 102;

    insert_hashmap(my_hmap, &k, &v);
```

Nope. As I said above, the code says that the keys to the map are *strings*, yet you pass an int to it. This [invokes undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which you must avoid.

```c
    printf("done!");
```

There is a `\n` missing after the `"done!`". Without this newline, there is no guarantee that the "done!" is printed at all. That's for historic reasons, but it's a good rule. Every program that outputs text should do so in whole lines.

Summary: you got many things right and many things wrong, but that's to be expected when you submit your code for review.

For comparison, here is the [header](https://github.com/NetBSD/src/blob/trunk/usr.bin/make/hash.h) and [implementation](https://github.com/NetBSD/src/blob/trunk/usr.bin/make/hash.c) that's very similar to yours. You can practice reading other people's code using that, and if you find any differences, have a look at the GitHub history of these files. They are more than 27 years old and have evolved a lot in all this time.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth review! In the test code, I am mapping ints to ints, rather than strings to ints; I accidentally got a string hash function.

Comment: No, not quite. In the test code you are _pretending_ to map ints to ints. In reality you just invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance, but how does it invoke undefined behavior?

Comment: By calling `strlen` on an int pointer. I don't think the C standard makes any guarantee for this.

Answer (score 1):

**Use a prime number for the number of buckets.**

To expand [@RoRoland Illig](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/253481/29485) idea about  `% hmap->num_buckets`.

Insure the array index is within range by modding with the number of buckets:

```
size_t hashed_key = hmap->hfunc(key);
// struct Pair* entry = hmap->buckets[hashed_key];
struct Pair* entry = hmap->buckets[hashed_key % hmap->num_buckets];
```

If `hmap->hfunc()` is a *good* hash function, then the value of `hmap->num_buckets` makes little difference.

Yet if  `hmap->hfunc()` has weaknesses, performing `% some_prime` improves the hashing.

A bucket number of `750000` or `0xB71B0` emphasizes the last four bits of `hashed_key` over the other bits.  A prime would nominally equally use  all the bits of `hashed_key`.